# Running multiple async queries with ADODB - callbacks not always firing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, adodb

I have an Excel workbook that fires three queries to a database to populate three tables on hidden sheets, and then runs three 'refresh' scripts to pull this data through to three visible presentation sheets (one per query). Running this synchronously is quite slow: The total time to refresh is the sum of the time of each of the three queries, plus the sum of the time for each 'refresh' script to run.

I'm aware that VBA isn't multi-threaded, but I thought it would be possible to speed things up a bit by firing the queries off asynchronously (thus allowing some clean-up work to be done whilst they were executing), and then doing the population / refresh work for each sheet as the data comes back.

I rewrote my script as follows (note that I've had to remove the connection strings, query strings etc and make the variables generic):

```
Private WithEvents cnA As ADODB.Connection
Private WithEvents cnB As ADODB.Connection
Private WithEvents cnC As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub StartingPoint()
    'For brevity, only listing set-up of cnA here. You can assume identical
    'set-up for cnB and cnC
    Set cnA = New ADODB.Connection

    Dim connectionString As String: connectionString = "<my conn string>"
    cnA.connectionString = connectionString

    Debug.Print "Firing cnA query: " & Now
    cnA.Open
    cnA.Execute "<select query>", adAsyncExecute  'takes roughly 5 seconds to execute

    Debug.Print "Firing cnB query: " & Now
    cnB.Open
    cnB.Execute "<select query>", adAsyncExecute  'takes roughly 10 seconds to execute

    Debug.Print "Firing cnC query: " & Now
    cnC.Open
    cnC.Execute "<select query>", adAsyncExecute  'takes roughly 20 seconds to execute

    Debug.Print "Clearing workbook tables: " & Now
    ClearAllTables
    TablesCleared = True
    Debug.Print "Tables cleared: " & Now
End Sub

Private Sub cnA_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ...)
    Debug.Print "cnA records received: " & Now
    'Code to handle the recordset, refresh the relevant presentation sheet here, 
    'takes roughly < 1 seconds to complete
    Debug.Print "Sheet1 tables received: " & Now
End Sub

Private Sub cnB_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ...)
    Debug.Print "cnB records received: " & Now
    'Code to handle the recordset, refresh the relevant presentation sheet here, 
    'takes roughly 2-3 seconds to complete
    Debug.Print "Sheet2 tables received: " & Now
End Sub

Private Sub cnC_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ...)
    Debug.Print "cnC records received: " & Now
    'Code to handle the recordset, refresh the relevant presentation sheet here, 
    'takes roughly 5-7 seconds to complete
    Debug.Print "Sheet3 tables received: " & Now
End Sub
```

Typical expected debugger output:

```
Firing cnA query: 21/02/2014 10:34:22
Firing cnB query: 21/02/2014 10:34:22
Firing cnC query: 21/02/2014 10:34:22
Clearing tables: 21/02/2014 10:34:22
Tables cleared: 21/02/2014 10:34:22
cnB records received: 21/02/2014 10:34:26
Sheet2 tables refreshed: 21/02/2014 10:34:27
cnA records received: 21/02/2014 10:34:28
Sheet1 tables refreshed: 21/02/2014 10:34:28
cnC records received: 21/02/2014 10:34:34
Sheet3 tables refreshed: 21/02/2014 10:34:40
```

The three queries can come back in different orders depending on which finishes first, of course, so sometimes the typical output is ordered differently - this is expected.

Sometimes however, one or two of the `cnX_ExecuteComplete` callbacks don't fire at all. After some time debugging, I'm fairly certain the reason for this is that if a recordset returns whilst one of the callbacks is currently executing, the call does not occur. For example:

- query A, B and C all fire at time 0
- query A completes first at time 3, `cnA_ExecuteComplete` fires
- query B completes second at time 5
- `cnA_ExecuteComplete` is still running, so `cnB_ExecuteComplete` never fires
- `cnA_ExecuteComplete` completes at time 8
- query C completes at time 10, `cnC_ExecuteComplete` fires
- query C completes at time 15

Am I right in my theory that this is the issue? If so, is it possible to work around this, or get the call to 'wait' until current code has executed rather than just disappearing?

One solution would be to do something extremely quick during the `cnX_ExecuteComplete` callbacks (eg, a one-liner `Set sheet1RS = pRecordset` and a check to see if they're all done yet before running the refresh scripts synchronously) so the chance of them overlapping is about zero, but want to know if there's a better solution first.

Comment: +1 for well written question

Comment: Look at your *`Typical Expected debugger output:`*, if the `cnA` runs 5 seconds then the first expected *log* past `Tables Cleared` should actually be `Debug.Print "cnA records received: " & Now`. You've got `cnB records received` which is a bit **misleading** according to your logic. I noticed you said 5sec, 10sec, 20sec but according to that the expected should be `cnA`, `cnB`, `cnC`. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @mehow The estimates are rough at best - it may be best to ignore those comments. The execution time of the queries vary - where it says "roughly 5 seconds" you can take that to mean anywhere from 3 seconds to 8, and "roughly 10 seconds" can take anywhere from 7 seconds to 15. It's entirely possible that `cnB` finishes before `cnA`, or `cnC` finishes before `cnB` (or something *really* slows down `cnA` and `cnC` finishes before it) - it all querying against an external server means it's entirely dependent on the network, present server load, record locking etc etc.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I have answered for you see if that helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess I am not able to explain why some your 'refresh scripts' don't always fire. It's a strange behavior that sometimes they run and sometimes they don't. I can't really see your entire script but I can show you how I have adopted your code and *made it work each time*.

*Note: your question is somehow related to [ExecuteComplete ADODB Connection event not fired with adAsyncExecute parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167478/executecomplete-adodb-connection-event-not-fired-with-adasyncexecute-parameter)*

I have added 3 stored procedures on my SQL server; `sp_WaitFor5`, `sp_WaitFor10`, `sp_WaitFor20` to simulate the delay of query execution time.

As simple as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_WaitFor5
AS
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
```

for all 3 delays.

Then in my **`Module1`** I added a very simple code to call the custom class

```
Option Explicit

Private clsTest As TestEvents

Sub Main()
    Cells.ClearContents
    Set clsTest = New TestEvents
    Call clsTest.StartingPoint
End Sub
```

Then I have renamed the class module to **`TestEvents`** and added a slightly modified version of your code

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents cnA As ADODB.Connection
Private WithEvents cnB As ADODB.Connection
Private WithEvents cnC As ADODB.Connection

Private i as Long

Public Sub StartingPoint()

    Dim connectionString As String: connectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYSERVER\INST; UID=username; PWD=password!"

    Debug.Print "Firing cnA query(10 sec): " & Now
    Set cnA = New ADODB.Connection
    cnA.connectionString = connectionString
    cnA.Open
    cnA.Execute "sp_WaitFor10", adExecuteNoRecords, adAsyncExecute

    Debug.Print "Firing cnB query(5 sec): " & Now
    Set cnB = New ADODB.Connection
    cnB.connectionString = connectionString
    cnB.Open
    cnB.Execute "sp_WaitFor5", adExecuteNoRecords, adAsyncExecute

    Debug.Print "Firing cnC query(20 sec): " & Now
    Set cnC = New ADODB.Connection
    cnC.connectionString = connectionString
    cnC.Open
    cnC.Execute "sp_WaitFor20", adExecuteNoRecords, adAsyncExecute

End Sub


Private Sub cnA_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print vbTab & "cnA_executeComplete START", Now
    For i = 1 To 55
        Range("A" & i) = Rnd(1)
    Next i
    Debug.Print vbTab & "cnA_executeComplete ENDED", Now
End Sub

Private Sub cnB_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print vbTab & "cnB_executeComplete START", Now
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Range("B" & i) = Rnd(1)
    Next i
    Debug.Print vbTab & "cnB_executeComplete ENDED", Now
End Sub

Private Sub cnC_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print vbTab & "cnC_executeComplete START", Now
    For i = 1 To 55
        Range("C" & i) = Rnd(1)
    Next i
    Debug.Print vbTab & "cnC_executeComplete ENDED", Now
End Sub
```

I have not really changed much except the [extra parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559(v=vs.85).aspx) for `Execute` and some code which populates activesheet just to *take the time*.

---

Now, I am able to run different variations/configurations. I can rotate the execution time for connection objects. I can have `cnA` 5 sec, `cnB` 10sec, `cnC` 20sec. I can swap/adjust the execution times for each of the `_ExecuteComplete` events.

From testing on my own I can assure you all 3 are **always** executed.

Here's some logs based on a configuration similar to yours

```
Firing cnA query(10 sec): 24/02/2014 12:59:46
Firing cnB query(5 sec): 24/02/2014 12:59:46
Firing cnC query(20 sec): 24/02/2014 12:59:46
    cnB_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 12:59:51 
    cnB_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:00:21 
    cnA_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:00:21 
    cnA_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:00:21 
    cnC_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:00:22 
    cnC_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:00:22
```

In the above example as you can see, all 3 queries are fired asynchronously.

`cnA` returns the handle after 5 secs which makes `cnB` the first one to have the event (*'refresh script'*) run in the hierarchy as `cnC` takes the longest.

Since `cnB` *comes back* first, it fires it's `cnB_ExecuteComplete` event procedure. The `cnB_ExecuteComplete` itself it's set to take some time execute (*iterates 1 million times and fills in column B with random numbers*. Note: cnA populates column A, cnB col B, cnC col C). Looking at the above log it takes exactly 30 seconds to run.

While the `cnB_ExecuteComplete` is doing its job /taking up resources (*and as you know VBA is single threaded*)  the `cnA_ExecuteComplete` event is added up to the queue of TODO processes. So, you can think of it like a queue. While something is being taken care of the next thing has to just wait for its turn in the end.

---

If I change the configuration; `cnA` 5 sec, `cnB` 10 sec, `cnC` 20 sec and have each of the *'refresh scripts'* iterate 1 million times then

```
Firing cnA query(5 sec): 24/02/2014 13:17:10
Firing cnB query(10 sec): 24/02/2014 13:17:10
Firing cnC query(20 sec): 24/02/2014 13:17:10
one million iterations each
    cnA_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:17:15 
    cnA_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:17:45 
    cnB_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:17:45 
    cnB_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:18:14 
    cnC_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:18:14 
    cnC_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:18:44
```

Clearly proved my point from the first example.

Also, tried with `cnA` 5 sec, `cnB` 5 sec, `cnC` 5 sec

```
Firing cnA query(5 sec): 24/02/2014 13:20:56
Firing cnB query(5 sec): 24/02/2014 13:20:56
Firing cnC query(5 sec): 24/02/2014 13:20:56
one million iterations each
    cnB_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:21:01 
    cnB_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:21:31 
    cnA_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:21:31 
    cnA_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:22:01 
    cnC_executeComplete START             24/02/2014 13:22:01 
    cnC_executeComplete ENDED             24/02/2014 13:22:31
```

Which also completes/executes all 3.

---

Like I've said I can't see your entire code, maybe you're having an unhandled error somewhere in your code, maybe there is something misleading you to think that one `_ExecuteComplete` is not executing at all. Try to make changes to your code to reflect the one I have given you and run a few more text on our own. I will be looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: Interesting... I changed my code back to this format where each `_ExecuteComplete` takes a while to complete, and it now seems to be working as advertised ('queueing' each callback if one is currently executing). I'll keep debugging to see if the problem occurs again. It may well have been something as dumb as a missing `Debug.Print` in one of my `_ExecuteComplete`s that meant I wasn't seeing one of them on output, or some other Friday Afternoon WTF. Leaving the question open until I'm confident whatever the problem was has gone away, and if so I'll accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Kai I am glad it gave you some insight on the issue. Can you explain what do you mean by *`I changed my code back to this format where each _ExecuteComplete takes a while to complete`*?

Comment: Sure. In my question, each `_ExecuteComplete` takes 'x' seconds to complete due to the code that refreshes the presentation sheet. I thought this was what may be causing callbacks to 'drop', so I removed this code and replaced it with a quick check to see if all 3 `_ExecuteComplete` had been called and then did the refresh code afterward (http://txt.do/1gvj). This made each `_ExecuteComplete` take almost no time at all to complete, so I could be 99% confident they weren't 'overlapping'. A bit hacky, but it seemed a decent solution at the time.

Comment: @Kai right, I wouldn't want to say this for sure yet but I'm silently thinking you might have been missing a `Debug.Print` in one of the `_ExecuteComplete`s

Comment: It's entirely possible

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an answer that will help you some of the time, but not all the time.

Sometimes your Recordset.Open or your Command.Execute ignores the `AdAsynchFetch` parameter.

That is to say: the problem manifests immediately, when you are requesting, and it's not an issue with the application in an unresponsive state when ADODB calls back with a populated recordset.

Fortunately, this is something you can trap in the code; and there are three things that occur when AdFetchAsynch is ignored:

1. The Execute or Open method runs synchronously **and populates a
   recordset**.
2. The `ExecuteComplete` event is never raised.

You can see where I'm going with this...

If your recordset-requesting code detects an open recordset before it exits, pass the open recordset straight into your existing `_FetchComplete` event procedure:

```
Set m_rst = New ADODB.Recordset  ' declared at module level With Events

With m_rst

    Set .ActiveConnection = ThisWorkbook.MyDBConnection

    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly

     Err.Clear
    .Open SQL, , , , adCmdText + adAsyncFetch

End With

If m_rst.State = adStateOpen Then

    ' This block will only run if the adAsyncFetch flag is ignored
    If m_rst.EOF And m_rst.BOF Then
        MsgPopup "No matching data for " & DATASET_NAME, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Empty data set", 90
    ElseIf m_rst.EOF Then
        m_rst.MoveFirst
        m_rst_FetchComplete Nothing, GetStatus(m_rst), m_rst
    Else
        m_rst_FetchComplete Nothing, GetStatus(m_rst), m_rst
    End If

    Set m_rst = Nothing

ElseIf m_rst.ActiveConnection.Errors.Count > 0 Then

    m_rst_FetchComplete m_rst.ActiveConnection.Errors(0), adStatusErrorsOccurred, m_rst
    Set m_rst = Nothing

ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgPopup "Microsoft Excel returned error &H" & Hex(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error requesting " & DATASET_NAME, 60
    Set m_rst = Nothing

ElseIf m_rst.State < adStateOpen Then

    MsgPopup "Microsoft Excel was unable to request data for " & DATASET_NAME & ": no error information is available", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error requesting " & DATASET_NAME, 60
    Set m_rst = Nothing

Else

    ' Fetch progess is not available with the OLEDB driver I am using
    ' m_rst_FetchProgress 0, 100, GetStatus(m_rst), m_rst

End If
```

Obviously this is going to be useless if the `_FetchComplete` event is never raised: 'open' runs asynchronously and the method exits with a recordset in state adStateConnecting or adStateFetching and you're totally reliant on the `m_rst_FetchComplete` event procedure.

But this fixes the issue some of the time.

Next: you need to check that `Application.EnableEvents` is never set to false when you might have a recordset request out in the ether. I'm guessing that you've thought of that, but it's the only other thing that I can think of.

Also:

A tip for readers who are new to ADODB coding: consider using `adCmdStoredProc` and calling your saved query or your recordset-returning function by name instead of using 'SELECT * FROM' and `adCmdText`.

A late answer here, but other people will encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not sure why the event does not always get fired for you.
For me, the test always worked (tested with 100 000 rows and 14 columns), but I'm not sure about the size of your database and complexity of the queries that you are executing.

I've got a remark though.

There is an important difference between the `ExecuteComplete` and the `FetchComplete` Event.

The `ExecuteComplete` fires after a command has finished executing (in your example, the command object is internally created by ADO). This does not necessarily mean that all records have been fetched by the time this callback fires.

Hence, if you need the returned recordset to work with, you should listen to the `fetchComplete` callback, that only fires when the recordset was entirely fetched.