# MS Access 2010 Screen hangs when calling procedure via pass through query

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, ms-access-2010

I am facing issue related to the performance in MS Access 2010, calling procedure via Pass Through Query, ms access screen hangs. 
If i run procedure it took one hour to complete and come out successfully, but if i am running through vba than screen is not responding.

```
    Private Sub abc_Click()

    Dim db As Database Set db = CurrentDb()

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "PRocedure", acViewNormal, acEdit   
End Sub
```

I am using User DSN
[image]
Please suggest me some good way so that ms access screeen does not hang and it comes out when procedure completes successfully.

Comment: It looks like you have timeout issue. 1 hour it's very long time. Am i right that when you run procedure from some sql tool it works fine? Does procedure return something?

Comment: @Sergey: In pass through query i have set timeout as 0. Yes, procedure is running fine with sql tool. Procedure is not returning any thing. I am commenting on behalf of the user. Please suggest some way to get out from this problem

Answer (score 0):

As procedure doesn't return anything you can use async execute using ADODB.

You can find some details here:
[Running multiple async queries with ADODB - callbacks not always firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933099/running-multiple-async-queries-with-adodb-callbacks-not-always-firing)

When you run your procedure you can track process via periodical requests to progress table. Of course this procedure should be modified to show progress.