# Control Database form Excel through VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to create an excel addin which has set of Functions to pull value from the database (I use MS SQL Server). So my query will return only one record set. I use something like below in my vba code.

[Using Excel VBA to run SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385245/using-excel-vba-to-run-sql-query)

But the problem with this is if I have my custom function in 100 cells, the macro makes connection to the DB everytime and retrive data from the DB.

Is there a way where I can make one connection and use that connection to write as many queries as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, run all your 100 function/ loops to access the database. One you've finished then close the connection. Look at your modified code below...

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String

    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=INSTANCE\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString

    '>>>> run 100 loops
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 100
        Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table" + 1 + ";")

        ' Check we have data.
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            ' Transfer result.
            ' I assume that you've 100 Sheets
            Sheets(i).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        ' Close the recordset
            rs.Close
        Else
            MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
        End If
    Next

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I've add 100 loops and run it before the connection to database is closed.
Hope it useful.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. If I understand the OP correctly then he/she wants to pull one value at a time with the sub. Maybe this will even be part of a UDF. So, looping through several SQL queries won't work unless there is a way to aggregate all queries beforehand (so the sub knows about all the queries it has to run).

Comment: He/She create a method (Sub ConnectSQLServer), it's a method or subroutine and not a function. Let's assume that he/she will create a function (UDF) and call the ConnectSqlServer method from that function, well....I think it a bad Idea because the code will run so slowly.

Comment: Yes I want to pull only one value. Consider a table that has financial data for 500 US Companies. The column names are Ticker (Primary Key), Year, Revenue, Costs, Profit.. Suppose if I want to pull revenue for Apple Inc. for 2015, I will use (SELECT Revenue FROM <Database> WHERE Ticker ='AAPL',Year = '2015'). So it will return only one value (ie. the revenue number)... I am trying to create a excel function something like GetCompanyData(<Ticker>,<Year>)..

Comment: @CheriesMewengkang Just as I thought: he/she wants a UDF but doesn't know it yet. Once he/she comes to realize what `volatile` stands for he/she probably wants that too. So, this AddIn will require a `recalculate` button which scans the entire Excel file for any occurrence of the UDF, preaggregates all these SQL calls into one and then passes it all over to the SQL at once. Afterwards the result of the query (coming back from the server) will have to be passed back to all the functions individually. That's a massive project! Hence, I will flag to close this post as too broad.

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for explaining the gravity of this. Do you think this is doable in VBA? Hey this is Jayanth btw so its "he" :)

Comment: Remember that VBA is a synchronous programming. For every UDF, the first code will be executed before the second code and so on. So if you put your UDF on 5 cells, that's mean you have 5 copy of your code and it'll be executed one by one. Imagine if you use the same UDF on thousands or millions cells...? Think about the performance, converting UDF into a method is an alternative to speed up your code.

Comment: @CheriesMewengkang VBA **can** be synchronous. But it also allows for asynchronous programming. I have done this already several times for uploading data from Excel to an SQL server. **While** Excel VBA is still waiting for the SQL server to process the first query, Excel can use this time and already preaggregate the next query for the server. Then, once the SQL server says "I am done." Excel VBA gets notified and the next query can be sent to the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933099/running-multiple-async-queries-with-adodb-callbacks-not-always-firing

Comment: Thanks to ActiveX Data Object which come with asynchronous feature, but VBA still synchronous and using UDF to access a database (for me) will kill performance unless you working with small data and small number of UDF. While you use it to thousands rows.....not only client (Excel) but the server (where database reside) should handle thousands connection at the same time. After all the choice is yours...!

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of cases do not do db operations in loops. This is time consuming and not proper useage. Instead, in a loop create select, insert or whatsoever statement and then complate the loop operations and calculations then open the connection just one time and send request (created sql script) to db and get response from db then close connection. Thats all. db operations must be sparated from dailiy and recursive opeations.(antipattern) best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: while this is not a direct solution to the problem described in the post I would like to add this approach as a much faster and easier solution to the problem described.

Step 1: create a (possibly hidden) sheet where you pull all the SQL data that you need in this Excel file. Pull the data into **one** table with all the necessary columns / dimensions to get the data afterwards from this table.

Here is what I mean by that. Let's assume that you need in this Excel file some data from the table `Users` on the SQL server as well as some information from a `StockMarket` table on the server. From the table `Users` you want the UserID, the first name, last name, and the job title. From the table `StockMarket` you will need the Stockmarket ID and the price for this particular share. As these prices are by date you also need the the quote date for the price.

Now, since you want all in one table you must think of a smart way to combine all this data into one table. One approach could be the following:
[image]

Afterwards you can get all the data from the above table with lookup functions like these:

```
=INDEX(SQLdata,MATCH(1,(SQLdata[Table]="Users")*(SQLdata[UserID]=25),0),4)
```

<sub>Note, that I named the table SQLdata to make it easier when looking at the formula and understanding it. Also, like this you can easily scan your Excel file for any reference to this table.</sub>

Another approach could be the following to make the table more concise:
[image]

Note, that this time I am mixing `Strings` with `Numbers` and also `Strings` with `Date`s (which is very poor design and for some people here even impossible to think of). Also, the column headers are now less descriptive. Yet, this works too:

```
=INDEX(SQLrev,MATCH(1,(SQLrev[Table]="Users")*(SQLrev[Dimension1]=25),0),5)
```

<sub>Note, that I called the table this time SQLrev.</sub>

Both solutions allow you also to aggregate data from the table. So, if you want (for example) the average price for Apple in 2017 then you can use the following formula to sum up the the quotes for this year and divide them by 3:

```
=SUM(IF("StockMarket"=SQLrev[Table];1;0)*IF("AAPL"=SQLrev[Dimension1];1;0)*SQLdata[Price])/3
```

The most notable advantage for this approach is that you merely have to update one table in the entire Excel file which means that there is only **one** SQL pull from the server.

The most notable disadvantage (apart from the SQL select which might get pretty complicated to write) is that you need to know of all the data that needs to reside in this table. If the data is not pulled into this table then none of the above formulas will be able to retrieve these values.

While this approach certainly has its downsides this is much easier to implement than the Excel AddIn you are aiming for.

<sub>All above formulas are array formulas and must be entered pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`. For more information on array formulas please read the following: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7</sub>

Comment: @user626994 While it is definitely possible to write such an AddIn as you describe it, the above solution is much easier to implement and requires no knowledge of VBA. So, maybe this solution is more suitable for you at this point.