# EXCEL INDEX and MATCH formula: Setting lookup_value as an "array"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a huge challenge in excel.

For the following logic of array and match:

```
    {=INDEX(array, MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, match_type))}
```

How may I set "lookup_value" as a concatenated "array"?

For example: A2&B2:B10, and that it look into the lookup_array, as A2&B2; A2&B3;...,A2&B10. And finally returned tha concatenated value that matched the lookup_array.

My case is shown in the attached image.

[case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9Kha.png)

Comment: With your example you are looking up and returning the lookup value as you are searching the same array.  so not sure what you really want.  can you mock up some data and expected outcome?

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695455/control-database-form-excel-through-vba/42720826#42720826

Comment: Hi, I just attached an image to my original post. It shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You will have 8 or 9 lookup return values(depending on which example), some of which might be #N/A. If you need the first one matched, then wrap the match with `IFERROR(INDEX(Process!$C:$C, MIN(IFERROR(MATCHFUNCTION, 1E9))), "Not Found")`, where MATCHFUNCTION is the entire match construct

Comment: MacroMarc... your solution worked!.. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula in B2 on Material and copy/drag down:

```
=INDEX(Process!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Process!$A$5:$A$8)/((Process!$A$5:$A$8=A2)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Process!$C$5:$C$8,Station!$A:$A,0)))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Scott Craner... it didn't work... shows all results as "#NUM!"

Comment: Well. Not sure why. It obviously worked for me, I did not photo shop the picture.

Comment: Did you change the `,` to `;`

Comment: Yes. My Excel is in spanish version.

Comment: Probably this error is related to the following? ---> Mi data is in "text" format, except for "Material", which is in "general" format.